# Failing to refactor a React render prop component into 2 components

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to refactor the following component so I can separate the outer / inner components.

```
// outer component
<Draggable>
    {(provided) => (
        <div
            className={`${styles.listWrapper} ${scrollbarClassName}`}
            ref={provided.innerRef}
            {...provided.draggableProps}
        >
            // This is the inner component I'd like to extract:
            <div className={`${styles.column} ${scrollbarClassName}`}>
                // However I'm using the provided props here:
                <div {...provided.dragHandleProps}>
                    <ColumnHeader {...columnHeaderProps} />
                </div>                              
            </div>
        </div>
    )}
</Draggable>
```

I'd like to be able to use it this way or similar, but I am not sure how to pass the props through children so I can use the `provided` prop in my inner component inside `DraggableColumn`:

```
const Draggable = <DraggableContainer>
    {(provided) => (
        <div
            className={`${styles.listWrapper} ${scrollbarClassName}`}
            ref={provided.innerRef}
            {...provided.draggableProps}
        >
            // How to pass provided to children and then use it in DraggableColumn below
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )}
</DraggableContainer>

const DraggableColumn = () => <DraggableContainer>
            <div className={`${styles.column} ${scrollbarClassName}`}>
                // How to get access to provided?
                <div {...provided.dragHandleProps}>
                    <ColumnHeader {...columnHeaderProps} />
                </div>                              
            </div>
        </DraggableContainer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something like the following:

```js
const DraggableContainer = props => {
  const provided = {
    foo: "bar",
    baz: () => console.log("hello world")
  };
  return props.children(provided);
};

const Draggable = props => {
  return (
    <DraggableContainer>
      {provided => props.children(provided)}
    </DraggableContainer>
  );
};

const DraggableColumn = props => {
  console.log('DraggableColumn.props', props)
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>DraggableColumn</h2>
      <p>provided: {JSON.stringify(props.provided)}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Draggable>{provided => <DraggableColumn provided={provided} />}</Draggable>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("app")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Basically, what you're doing here is recreating the same functionality that `DraggableContainer` provides by utilizing the `children prop` pattern:

- [reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#using-props-other-than-render](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#using-props-other-than-render)

One caveat is that `Draggable` will always be expecting `props.children` to be a function, meaning that the following will work:

```js
<Draggable>
  {(provided) => {
    return <DraggableColumn provided={provided} />;
  }}
</Draggable>
```

But this will not because `props.children` is not a function, unlike the example above:

```js
<Draggable>
  <p>Hello World</p>
</Draggable>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does help, thanks a lot. For some reason, I had tried to create a `Context` and then `useContext` but something didn't work.

Comment: @GregForel Yeah in this case I'd rather just utilize the pattern above instead of introducing `context`. It could get messy since you will have to manage multiple states for `provided` to make sure they are synchronized across all components that are using it.

Answer (score 0):

To pass a prop you need to declare it inside of the <>

For example

```
<Draggable provided={this.state.provided}>
  <div>
    Some Stuff
  </div>
</Draggable>
```

Then you can do `this.props.provided` inside the draggable component.

Comment: I'm realising I'm not sure how to ask the question properly. I know how to pass a prop, but in my case it's passing it to `children` that I'm not sure how to do, and then in `DraggableColumn` I also don't know how to get the props I passed through children

Comment: Read @goto1 answer to see if it helps. 

I find your code a little hard to follow and not exactly sure what answer you are looking for.